# How can I run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade commands automatically?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container where I run a few commands as a root user each time it is created from an image.
Is it possible to automate running these commands as a root administrator user each time my container is created?

```
# apt-get update

# apt-get upgrade

# apt-get install -y vim
```

Comment: Which image is it? Do you build that image?

Comment: It is php: image: pimcore/pimcore:PHP7.4-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a ready-made Docker image, and want additional package(s) on top of it, writing a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) would be "automation" of the commands. Using this you can create a new image with what you want pre-installed.

Example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM pimcore/pimcore:PHP7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y vim
```

Then use the `docker build` command to build an image with a name (tag) that you want.

Example below creates image named `my-phpapache:7.4`, you can use a name that makes sense to you. This image will have `vim` installed.

```
docker build -t my-phpapache:7.4 .
```

Note the `.`, this should be run in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`.

You may find that using the `Dockerfile` to copy configuration into the image may eliminate the need to have `vim` installed in it.